# How can I animate a circular scrolling list in Unity?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

Almost newbie here, I'm trying to create a circular scrolling list for a UI, but I'm stuck and I'm not sure I'm using the right tools.

What I'm trying to obtain is a Menu showing three voices, arranged vertically, with the one in the middle being highlighted.

When the user press the up (or down) arrow, the voices moves down (or up), the last one fades out and another one (that I pick from a array of strings) appears in the first slot.
[Example in the next image]

At the moment I have created five objects "slots", being a transform with a text component, the first and the last being set with alpha to 0; the second, third and fourth being visible.
When a user press up, the objects scroll down, and the text in the fifth position (invisible) go to the first position (still invisible), and updates his .text field to contain the right voice.
My problem is with the animations to make the options scroll.
If I use a state machine behaviour for every slot I cannot have only a state for every position because the motion associated with a state should come from different sides (ex: an object can reach the position 3 from 4 and 2).
So I tried to make animations with a single frame and let the blending between the states do the job and it works

Example and first state machine:

[image]

*(the translations are activated by trigger goUp/goDown)*

but of course I cannot use the curves in the animation panel in unity, and the blending feels a bit cluncky.

So I made a more complicated SM, with every state associated with an animation (so my states are: 0to1, 1to2, ..., 1to0, 2to1, etc)

Overly tangled state machine:

[image]

*(I removed the translation from FadeIn to increase the "readability")*

but I feel like I choose an overly complex and not easily expandable way to create a relatively simple thing.

Am I doing the right thing or I should consider dropping the SM and handle everything by script (and most important, create the animations by script)?

Comment: What do you manage in your animations ? Only positions ? If so, using an easing equation may be easier In my opinion. (check Robert Penner's)

Comment: I manage position and alpha, because when the first shown item goes towards the top it becomes invisible, and the same goes for the last item shown.
Thank you for your suggestion, I'll definitely check it out!

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with tweener suggestion. It would simplify it a lot.
Here is one of the decent plugin for tweenning
http://dotween.demigiant.com
It has extension for transforming game objects, such as move, rotate, scale. It also, expose a lot of nice functionality for other components, including colour with changing alpha.
So, I guess you will find it useful.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'm going to use it